# Installation of COCOAPI for python 3.5.2

Tags: python, makefile, installation, python-3.5, image-segmentation

I've heard that there's python version incompatibility issues with the original COCOAPI and that it doesn't work with python 3? And so I'm using this version: 
https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi

But I'm facing similar issues as when I was using the original COCOAPI.

after running: pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI,
I managed to get: Successfully built pycocotools

When I tried to make under the PythonAPI folder:
.../cocoapi-master/PythonAPI$ make

It returned without any errors:
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
rm -rf build

However, when I tried running: .../cocoapi-master/PythonAPI$ python Makefile
I keep getting this error:
File "Makefile", line 1
all:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I tried running: .../cocoapi-master/PythonAPI/demos$ python pycocoDemo.ipynb
I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pycocoDemo.ipynb", line 7, in 
"collapsed": true
NameError: name 'true' is not defined

Prior to this, I've tried running and installing the original cocoapi (https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/tree/master/PythonAPI) but it gave similar errors. I searched around and tried installing extra packages, upgrading pip version, etc, but none of it is working...Would someone please advise me? Your help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Python version: 3.5.2,
Pip version: 18.0,
Cython version: 0.28.5,
pycocotools-2.0,
numpy.version.version: '1.14.2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a makefile issue. Just ignore the makefile after make and things should be fine.

Comment: This seemed to work for me as well. I had to also restart cmd to run the pycoco statement.